# Showing node on top of other components in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I have a text field along with many components in my GridPane. When I start typing in this text field, I want to show a list view below it which contains the search results. This search results ListView should be on top of the other components in the GridPane and don't want it to be a modal pane and want to construct it at runtime. I tried with including this a a Popup, but it is visible even if we go to a different application in windows.
Could you please suggest what is the best way to approach this?

Comment: But with a stack pane can I position them where I want?

Comment: You may need to add another layout panel (e.g. `AnchorPane`) in the `StackPane` and add the positioned component in it. So, the `StackPane` gives you "on top" positioning and the `AnchorPane` gives you (x,y) positioning.